# How to handle Windows API LPTSTR output as a formal parameter output

Tags: c#, marshalling, user32

I'm trying to determine the classname of a window by calling `GetClassName()` on the `hWnd` that I receive from `FindWindowByCaption()`. But it's not working; all I see for the classname is garbage characters (specifically, four question marks and then some strange non-alphanumeric character). `GetClassName()`, as far as I understand it, writes data into the caller's buffer.

Here's my code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern System.IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern System.IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(System.IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetClassName(System.IntPtr hWnd,
                               [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
                               System.Text.StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

...

System.IntPtr hWndMyWindow = FindWindowByCaption(System.IntPtr.Zero, "My Window");
if (hWndMyWindow != null)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("hWndMyWindow = {0}", hWndMyWindow);
   System.Text.StringBuilder lpClassName = new System.Text.StringBuilder(256);
   lpClassName.Length = lpClassName.Capacity - 2;
   int len = GetClassName(hWndMyWindow, lpClassName, lpClassName.Length - 2);
   lpClassName.Length = len; // set length to the actual length of the classname
   System.Console.WriteLine("hWndMyWindow = {0}, classname = {1}", hWndMyWindow, lpClassName.ToString());
}
else
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("No such window.");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The `lpClassName` param of `GetClassName()` is an output... I expected `GetClassName()` to write the classname into the `StringBuilder`, but it's not working right.

Answer (score 1):

```
   [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
```

LPTStr does not mean what you think it does.  With the way you wrote these declarations, only UnmanagedType.LPStr can work.  Or better yet, completely omit this attribute, it is not necessary at all, the pinvoke marshaller already understands StringBuilder.

You are invoking the 1990s with these declarations, you are using the "Ansi" versions of these winapi functions.  The default for [DllImport] unfortunately.  It does not make sense to use them, nobody runs Windows 98 anymore.  Windows is a Unicode operating system at its heart, write the declarations to match:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern System.IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int GetClassName(System.IntPtr hWnd, 
                                   StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
```

FindWindowByCaption() is a bit too cute, just don't, pass `null` as the 1st argument.  Note that you have a bug in your error handling, FindWindow fails with IntPtr.Zero, not null.  And don't ignore error handling for GetClassName().  Just make a loud bang by throwing System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to apologize because I don't understand what you mean by "FindWindowByCaption() is a bit too cute". The DllImport lines are cut-and-pasted from some other SO post (or perhaps some other forum; I don't remember). I'm guessing from the fact that finding MSDN documentation on that function is impossible, and from what you said, that perhaps there really isn't any such function as FindWindowByCaption(), and somehow it's an alias of FindWindow()? Is that what the `EntryPoint = "FindWindow"` does? Do you see any benefit of such an alias?

Comment: Yes, it is an alias.  While possibly useful, particularly for mangled C++ identifier names, there is no real benefit if it is done wrong.  It isn't even necessary, C# support method overloads.  You can simply call it FindWindow() as well.  But just don't, the existing FindWindow() declaration works just as well when you pass null for the first argument.  The less hard-to-understand pinvoke the better.

Comment: Thank you again. You said "FindWindow fails with IntPtr.Zero, not null." MSDN documentaion (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to indicate that the return value is NULL on failure. Am I understanding something wrong? Or is this an issue with the DllImport declaration being wrong in the first place? (I hate it that C# doesn't have #include files; it makes no sense to me why we should have to declare a bunch of DllImports ourselves, and risk declaring them wrong; we should be able to do something like #include <Windows.h> like in C and C++.)

Comment: That's a C language null, not a .NET null.  You can use null only when you declared the function to return a pointer or an object.  You didn't, you appropriately declared it to return IntPtr.  Whose NULL value is IntPtr.Zero.  You don't have to hate it, writing interop code in C++/CLI is a very decent alternative.  Not exactly necessary if you just a few interop calls.  Please close your question, use the Ask Question button if you have more questions, that way other programmers can benefit from it as well.